# What do the .(dot) and , (comma) do in `select` function in R?

Tags: r

I am very familiar with how to use `select`to subset a dataset.

```
#data
mydata<-data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3), y = c(7, 8, 9))
mydata
  x y
1 1 7
2 2 8
3 3 9
```

For example, if I only want to keep variable x, I can run this code:

```
mydata %>% select(x)
```

No dot or comma is needed here. However, I don't quite understand what the dot and comma do in the following code when `select` is used with `mutate` and `rowMeans`. Why do we need them?

```
mydata %>% mutate (z = rowMeans(select(.,c(x, y)), na.rm=T))
  x y z
1 1 7 4
2 2 8 5
3 3 9 6
```

Comment: The `.` signifies the data, and `,` separates the arguments i.e. data from the columns you want to select i.e. `x, y`

Comment: If you check `help(select)` the documentation gives the usage as `select(.data, ...)` where `.data- A data frame, data frame extension (e.g. a tibble), or a lazy data frame (e.g. from dbplyr or dtplyr).` and `... - One or more unquoted expressions separated by commas....`

Comment: @akrun Thank you. But doesn't `mydata %>%` already signify the data I want to process? In this case, `mydata %>%` doesn't get passed down?

Comment: Yes, it does, but `select` is meant to be used standalone.  In the second call, you are kind of hacking by calling `select` to subset the columns.  Thus, when are passing `select` in `mutate` (which expects a single column to be transformed/created).  I added more description in the solution posted. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we check the `?select` documentation, the usage is

> select(.data, ...)

where

> .data - A data frame, data frame extension (e.g. a tibble), or a lazy data frame (e.g. from dbplyr or dtplyr). See Methods, below, for more details.

> ... -  One or more unquoted expressions separated by commas. Variable names can be used as if they were positions in the data frame, so expressions like x:y can be used to select a range of variables.

---

In the first case, OP is calling `select` as a separate expression

```
mydata %>%
     select(x)
```

Here, the `select` understands the `.data` as the output before the lhs of `%>%` i.e. the whole dataset, and 'x' will be the column to be selected, whereas in the second case

```
mydata %>% 
    mutate (z = rowMeans(select(.,c(x, y)), na.rm=TRUE))
```

`select` is called within another function `mutate` which normally expects a single column to be transformed/modified/created.  The function `rowMeans` needs a `matrix/data.frame/tibble` as input.  So, we `select` the subset of columns from the data (`.`) and pass it to `rowMeans` as a `data.frame` to return a `vector` of means

We may also use `cur_data()` and subset

```
mydata %>%
    mutate(z = rowMeans(cur_data()[c("x", "y")]))
  x y z
1 1 7 4
2 2 8 5
3 3 9 6
```